# Proper name and origin of tiny drill bit

Tags: hardware

Many years ago, I acquired a pile of tiny, drill-bit-like items that I use to make practically invisible holes in drywall to hang lightweight stuff from. They are indispensible, but I don't know what they're called. I got them from my dad, who in turn had received them from our dentist. They might be used in dentistry, or they might be from said-dentist's hobbies. I'd love to know the origin of this item! [image]

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks, Tanaya! Unfortunately, the questions on here have to _seek_ a lifehack. For example, "How can I drill nearly-invisible holes in drywall to hang lightweight stuff from?" We don't allow identification questions. Sorry! You may be able to get an answer on Quora.com.

Comment: @BrettFromLA is right, this doesn't belong in Lifehacks, but these do look exactly like the things I've seen my dentist using when performing root-canal on me.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Lifehacks was the closest StackExchange site I thought might work. "Medical Sciences" would have been much worse. :) Thanks @Lefty - if that hint doesn't work I'll try Quora. Cheers.

Comment: Dental drill bits. Generally only available from dental supply companies and usually only to dentists. Not a Home Depot item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like endodontic files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endodontic_files_and_reamers), or root canal tools if you prefer laymans terms.

You can probably find such tools on eBay if you want.

Answer (score 0):

While definitely not the same, you can find similar size bits with a Dremel or similar "Rotary Tool".

Answer (score 0):

Not to be repetitive those are files or broaches , not drill bits. They cut on the flanks by rotation and axial movement . A drill bit (should) only cut on the end. A drill bit does not have an enlarged shank for holding. I have several bits in that size range ; they require a collet to hold them. I never found a use for them except the larger ones are good to clean carburetor passages.